# Aggregate method using Restheart

Tags: mongodb, restheart

I have a remote database on MongoDB and i want to execute an aggregate method for grouping entries w.r.t. a certain field using restheart. My query looks like this

```
 db.musa.aggregate([{$group:{_id:"$username"}}])
```

this query returns a list of unique users in my database but i am not sure how to implement it using restheart. Is it even possible to do so?

Comment: currently restheart not support aggregate querys.

Comment: thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm from the restheart.org team...

a similar question has been already asked on github https://github.com/SoftInstigate/restheart/issues/55

I'm pasting here the answer:

> currently aggregate queries are not supported.
>
> note that this is in the roadmap and planned for next version
>
> jira task 41: https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/browse/RH-41
>
> as a workaround you can implement a custom application handler: documentation at https://softinstigate.atlassian.net/wiki/x/IoCw

Comment: I just updated the documentation page with a full example on how to execute an aggregation query via ApplicationHandler.

Comment: It is supported now

Answer (score 2):

RESTHeart release 1.1 is out and now can manage [aggregation operations](https://restheart.org/learn/aggregations/): both **aggregation pipelines** and **map reduce functions** are supported.

> Aggregations operations process data records and return computed results. Aggregation operations group values from multiple documents together, and can perform a variety of operations on the grouped data to return a single result.

Please let us know your [feedback](https://github.com/SoftInstigate/restheart/issues).